# UNION TABLE WITH VIEW WITHOUT DUPLICATE ROWS

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to join a Table with a View without any duplicate rows. but i am facing a problem while trying to do so . Getting Duplicate Rows (For example if view contains blank for column DeptManPower & Same row from Table Contains a Value for DeptManPower ). in that case i want to take the row from table not from view.

```
 SELECT * FROM(
    (SELECT 
           CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),[BOOKEDDATE],103) AS LogDate
          --,[ROWNUMBER] AS SlNo
          , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ROWNUMBER) SlNo
          ,[STAGEID] AS TypeOfJob
          ,[DESCRIPTION] AS JobPlanning
          ,'' AS DeptManPower
          ,'' AS ExtManPower
          ,'' AS JobCompliance
          ,[PTWNO] AS PTWNo
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,[LASTMODIFIEDBYDATE],103),103) AS TakenDate
          ,SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST( [LASTMODIFIEDBYDATE] as time) as VARCHAR),0,6)  AS TakenTime
          ,'' AS ReturndDate
          ,'' AS ReturndTime
          ,[MaterialReq] AS SparesUsed
      FROM [EDMS_CPL].[dbo].[VW_ALL_DEFECTS]
      WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),[BOOKEDDATE],103) ='18/07/2014' AND (STAGEID='4' OR STAGEID='21') 
     ) )A
      UNION
      SELECT* FROM
      (
      (
      SELECT 
               CONVERT(nvarchar(50),LogDate,103) AS LogDate
              --,Shift
              ,SlNo
              ,TypeOfJob 
              --,CASE TypeOfJob 
              --WHEN '4' THEN 'PTW Prepared - Without Isolation' 
              --                WHEN '21' THEN 'PTW Prepared - With Isolation'
                    --        WHEN '0' THEN 'N/A'
              --END AS TypeOfJob


              ,JobPlanning
              ,DeptManPower
              ,ExtManPower
              ,JobCompliance
              ,PTWNo
              ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),TakenDate,103) AS TakenDate
              ,TakenTime
              ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),ReturndDate,103) AS ReturndDate
              ,ReturndTime
              ,SparesUsed
        FROM tblMEIDLogEntry
        WHERE LogDate=CONVERT(DATETIME,'18/07/2014',103)
      ))B
    ORDER BY PTWNo


 Guide me how to do.
```

Comment: Please post table structure along with sample data and expected. By just seeing your query its very hard to understand what exactly you want. FYI nobody is going to read theoretical question here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather using ORDER BY PTWNo

**Use
GROUP BY**

Clause on the column in which you don't want duplicate data.

Comment: I tried GROUP BY ... It is not working.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'B.LogDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Because in GROUP BY clause you have to select specific columns rather than *. Change the first line * with column names and add the same columns in GROUP BY

Comment: Still Same. I need all the columns btw.

Comment: Yes but you need to mention name